# Excel VBA Macro to Hide Row When Not a Local Maximum

Tags: vba, excel

Please excuse my ignorance. I'm not an absolute programming beginner, but have little to no familiarity with VBA and the process of creating excel macros.

I have a table of data with values cyclically going up and down. What I'd like to do is hide a row if it is not a local maximum, so I can assess the trend from maximum to maximum. I've attempted to adapt another macro I found, which hides based on non-highlighting, and can't seem to get it just right.

Some things I know need changing:
1) I know I should not use"activesheet", substituting instead the actual name of the sheet in question.

2) I believe this program steps through every cell that has information in it. I only need to search through column "c". This should speed things up significantly (there are 11 other columns that I'm not interested in searching through).

3) I'm defining a local maximum as "cell Ci is a local maximum if C(i-1)C(i+1)". This causes problems when there are two cells in a row with the peak value for that local maximum. Is there a way around this? I think more than one cell per local maximum could be selected if I tried "average(x-1,x-2)average(x+1,x+2)"

4) I tried to redesign this code from someone else's code to hide rows based on not being highlighted. There are likely some bits that are unneeded and I'm too inexperienced to see them.

5) I'm searching through upwards of 15k-20k rows, because it's the output of a testing machine. I'm eager to implement any possible methods to speed this puppy up.

Here's the current code I'm trying (and thank you, thank you, thank you for your help!):

```
Public Sub HideUncoloredRows()

Dim startColumn As Integer
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim totalRows As Integer
Dim totalColumns As Integer
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim shouldHideRow As Integer

startColumn = 1     'column A
startRow = 1        'row 1
totalRows = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, startColumn).End(xlUp).Row

For currentRow = totalRows To startRow Step -1
    shouldHideRow = True
    totalColumns = ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'for each column in the current row, check for maximum
    For currentColumn = startColumn To totalColumns
        'if a local maximum is found, don't hide the row and move on to next row
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn) > ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow-1, currentColumn) and ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn) > ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow+1, currentColumn) Then
            shouldHideRow = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If shouldHideRow Then
        'drop into here if there was not a local maximum
        ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Edit: By local maximum, I mean that my graph is vaguely sinusoidal in nature, and I want to track the change in magnitude from peak to peak. The result is quite similar to this graph: http://steve.vbboys.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/dampedsin.jpg

Edit 2: Here's a made up set of data. The macro should not hide rows 3, 7, 13 and 14, and should hide all the other rows. https://www.dropbox.com/s/878e02uvb38edhd/Local%20Maxima.xlsx

Comment: What do you mean when you say "local maximum"?

Comment: There is a `MAX` function you could use, pass it the values, or array of values, or range of values, it will tell you what the max is, then would be best to simply *FILTER* instead of hide the rows that are not the max.

Comment: @Lopsided See edit at the bottom of my post. "local maximum" is the top of each peak in a sine-like curve.

Comment: @user2140261 Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that using 'MAX' will only give me one value: the highest point on the curve. I'm looking to track the change over time for _each_ of the peaks in a graph like this: http://steve.vbboys.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/dampedsin.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I full understand what your asking because I don't know what you mean by local maximum, but to answer your question on how to make it step through each cell in column C more efficiently you can use a Do While loop like this.

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

  K = 2 'Row 1 is a header so i start on row 2

  Do While ws.Cells(K, 3) <> ""
    'Code

    K = K + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: See the edit at the bottom of my original post. The graph is similar to a dampened sinusoidal curve, and I want to track the change/decrease in amplitude over time.

Answer (score 0):

Modified on 3/4. Note I have commented out code which is not needed; you don't need to loop through columns since you only care about "C"; Don't loop to row 1; Don't need the extra code ''If shouldHideRow Then' if you change the comparison from '>' to '<' Can you update your question to provide some sample data (actual numbers, and if it should be hidden) so we know what you want to do?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideUncoloredRows()

Dim startColumn As Integer
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim totalRows As Integer
Dim totalColumns As Integer
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim shouldHideRow As Integer

startColumn = 3     'column C
startRow = 1        'row 1
totalRows = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, startColumn).End(xlUp).Row

For currentRow = totalRows To startRow + 1 Step -1   ' 3/4 - Added +1
    shouldHideRow = True
    'totalColumns = ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'for each column in the current row, check for maximum
    'For currentColumn = startColumn To totalColumns
        'if a local maximum is found, don't hide the row and move on to next row
        'Debug.Print "Looking At: " & currentRow & "/" & startColumn & vbTab & currentRow - 1 & "/" & startColumn & vbTab & currentRow + 1 & "/" & startColumn
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, startColumn) < ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow - 1, startColumn) And ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, startColumn) < ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow + 1, startColumn) Then   ' 3/4 changed from > to <
            'shouldHideRow = False
            ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, startColumn).EntireRow.Hidden = True   ' 3/4 Just hide it!
            'Exit For
        End If
    'Next

    'If shouldHideRow Then   ' 3/4 Not needed with above change
    '    'drop into here if there was not a local maximum
    '    Debug.Print "Hide: " & currentRow & "/" & startColumn
    '    ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, startColumn).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    'End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. For the data I'm using, the first few points should never be one of the maxima I'm searching for. It would be no problem at all to start the search at the 10th or 20th row (a typical data set may have 20 maxima spread over 15,000 rows). I'll be updating my original post with mocked-up data, and what should be hidden.